# My Ubuntu does not want to know Arial

Tags: fonts

I do have many fonts with a version of Arial, but for some reason when programs are trying to use Arial it gets substituted with a totally unrelated font.

How the bug is seen in Libreoffice:
[image: How the bug is seen in Libreoffice.]

When I remove the 'fake Arial' font (Xixtrec in the picture), Arial just gets substituded for another wrong font.

Here is a list of installed fonts with name Arial in them:

```
/usr/share//truetype/ARRBD_ECL.ttf: Arial Rounded MT Bold Eclipse:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/XIXTREC.TTF: Xixtrec,Arial:style=rec Osa,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ILLUSION.TTF: Illusion\\:\\-Þ,Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/PIXEARG.TTF: Pixel Arial 11:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond-LightItalic.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond Light:style=Condensed Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/BALLONEY.TTF: Oh\\, Balloney,Arial:style=Regular,normal,Standard,Normaali,Normale,Standaard
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ARIALN.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arialbd.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova-LightItalic.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ArialRoundedMTStd-ExtraBold.otf: Arial Rounded MT Std,Arial Rounded MT Std Extra Bold:style=Extra Bold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ariblk.ttf: Arial,Arial Black:style=Black,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/SCAR6.TTF: Scarab,Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova.ttf: Arial Nova:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova-BoldItalic.ttf: Arial Nova:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond-BoldItalic.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond:style=Condensed Bold Italic,Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ariali.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/MKV/ARIALN.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial_italic.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond-Light.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond Light:style=Condensed Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova-Bold.ttf: Arial Nova:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond-Bold.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond:style=Condensed Bold,Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Eco2.ttf: Eco\\-Files,Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,onian,Fonts -,http\\:/,/membe,rs.xoom,.com/icon,ianfon,ts/Eco-F,ilesReg,ularEco,-Files,Eco-Fil,es1Eco,DMZmal
/usr/share/fonts/MKV/Arial Narrow_B0.ttf: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Bold,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/MKV/ariblk.ttf: Arial,Arial Black:style=Black,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ARR___.ttf: Arial Rounded MT:style=Regular
/home/hellerick/.local/share/fonts/ARIAL.TTF: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Arial Rounded MT.ttf: Arial Rounded MT:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arialbi.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/CHLORINZ.TTF: Chlorinez,Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova-Italic.ttf: Arial Nova:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond-Italic.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond:style=Condensed Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial_bold_italic.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/REPEATED.TTF: Repeated\\:\\-Þ,Arial:style=ising a,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ANAOneiroparmEni82.ttf: ANA\\-OneiroparmEni82,Arial:style=Oneiroparmeni82,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/bradybun.ttf: Brady Bunch,Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNovaCond.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Cond:style=Condensed,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial_bold.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ARLRDBD.TTF: Arial Rounded MT Bold:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ArialNova-Light.ttf: Arial Nova,Arial Nova Light:style=Light,Regular
```

Looks more than enough.

So where the problem could come from?

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve the problem please add the output of the installation command to your question.

Answer (score 3):

First I'm going to recommend the **free alternative**: *Liberation Sans* provides a very good replacement for *Arial*, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install fonts-liberation
```

This will install the following fonts:

- LiberationSans (Arial replacement)
- LiberationSerif (Times New Roman replacement)
- LiberationMono (Courier replacement)

---

If this doesn't fit your needs and you **really** need unfree Windows fonts, install them with:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This will install the following fonts:

- Andale Mono
- Arial Black
- Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Comic Sans MS (Bold)
- Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Impact
- Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Webdings

In the installation you will be forced to read a license agreement, you can confirm it using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I do meet this bug too often (e.g. when dealing with subtitled videos), so I shouldn't just leave it as it is. And ttf-mscorefonts-installer doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: Maybe you have some network issues about this package. If you have any Windows computer, you can copy `arial*.ttf` from `%windir%\fonts` to `/usr/share/fonts` or `~/.fonts`, if you prefer.

Comment: @user3129479 If it doesn't help then there's something wrong, please add the error output of the installation command to your question.

Comment: Installation was fine but it did not help. I suspect that one of my Arial files is corrupt. It takes the name Arial, but cannot be used, so Ubuntu takes wrong files instead. BTW I forgot to mention that only the regular version of the font makes the problem. Bold and Italic are fine.